# To what extent are (non-urgent) PIREPs used by meteorologists?

Tags: weather, meteorology

It's inevitable. At some point during your weather briefing, some underpaid, underappreciated briefer will say "*Pilot reports are requested.*" and you'll say "*Certainly, my good sir or madam! Why, the only thing that gets me out of bed in the morning is the chance to help my fellow aviators!*" and then you won't make one.

But let's say that you do make a non-urgent pilot report.  Briefers will give that information to pilots, but what about the meteorologists who actually make the forecasts?  Supposedly, they're interested in the information as well...

> "NBAA is excited about the new electronic submission form that should streamline the PIREP process, and **allow the information to get to the FAA air traffic controllers and the NWS Aviation Weather Center (AWC) forecasters** sooner," noted John Kosak, program manager, weather, NBAA Air Traffic Services.  [[1]](http://www.paperlesscockpit.com/2016/04/nbaa-members-nws-requesting-feedback-on-online-pirep-submission-form/)

but what are they used for once they're submitted?

Comment: Related: [Do You PIREP? Here’s Why You Should](http://www.alpa.org/news-and-events/air-line-pilot-magazine/do-you-pirep). PIREPs are used to validate high altitude weather forecasts.

Comment: PIREPs explain localized weather phenomena, typically along a path at a specific altitude in a specific location. Weather forecasters don't work that localized. They won't issue a forecast with "light to moderate turbulence experienced between 5000 and 7000 over the GRB VOR". They use weather balloons, radar, and other instrumentation to make the *area forecasts*. So while not an answer, I don't believe meteorologists use PIREPs at all, at least currently.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- my understanding is the *primary* use of PIREPs is to *validate* or *refute* forecasts -- hard to know if you got it right if you have no observations telling you what's actually up there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This NOAA newsletter](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/om/aviation/front/09dec-front.pdf) lists a number of specific ways that PIREPs are used by meteorologists:

- To "assess the strength and position of the jet stream"
- For thunderstorm and snow level forecasting
- For [forecast discussions](https://www.aviationweather.gov/fcstdisc) of regional weather phenomena, like "downslope wind storms in the lee of the Sierra Nevada"
- To "determine the likelihood of clouds thinning or burning off"

Their summary is:

> Better reports and observations, not only from PIREPS but also storm
>   spotters, Webcams and road weather networks help improve the picture
>   of what’s going on in the atmosphere. Automated temperature, wind and
>   humidity reports from MDCRS and the Aircraft Communications Addressing
>   and Reporting System in commercial aircraft also get incorporated into computer models. All of these observations lead to improved forecasts and warnings.

There are a few very generic references out there too. A 2014 edition of [FAA Safety Briefing](https://www.faa.gov/news/safety_briefing/2014/media/NovDec2014.pdf) says:

> The information will then be added to the distribution system to brief
>   other pilots, help generate inflight advisories like AIRMETs and
>   SIGMETs, as well as updates to the Current and Forecast Icing Products
>   (CIP/FIP), and improve overall forecast accuracy.

And an [AOPA article](https://www.aopa.org/asf/publications/inst_reports2.cfm?article=4793) has a brief mention:

> when the Aviation Weather Center (AWC) receives a pirep,
>   meteorologists use it to verify that their weather forecast is correct
>   or amend it if the pirep contradicts the forecast.

Finally, PIREPs (and [AIREPs](https://aviationweather.gov/airep/help)) are shown [on the NOAA website](https://aviationweather.gov/airep), although that probably isn't what you had in mind by meteorologists 'using' the information.